# Does $f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$? imply that $f^{-1}(A \cup B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$?

Tags: analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, logic

I have a training exercise that reads as follows:

> Let $f: M \rightarrow N$ and $A,B \subset M$ and $C,D \subset N$. Prove or disprove following statements:
>
> (a) $~f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$
>   (b) $~f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$
>   (c) $~f^{-1}(C \cup D) = f^{-1}(C) \cup f^{-1}(D)$
>   (d) $~f^{-1}(C \cap D) = f^{-1}(C) \cap f^{-1}(D)$

It is quite easy and has been done in many other Stackexchange questions to prove (a) and disprove (b). It seems logical to me that (c) and (not) (d) follow from this.

So would it be an appropriate or correct answer to write *(c) follows from (a) and not (d) follows from not (b)*?

**Remark:** Is there a mathematical correct and easy way to see/show that (c) follows from (a) and that not (d) follows from not (b)?

Comment: $(d)$ does hold.

Comment: Three of the statements are true, one is (sometimes) false.

Comment: @JonatanB.Bastos.  Give an example why.  I bet you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it seem logical to you that (c) follows from (a)? Is it because they both involve unions? This is a misconception. You ask if it is correct to assert that "(c) follows from (a)." If you don't know how (c) follows from (a), then you shouldn't claim it does. Have you tried to use (a) to prove (c)? In fact you cannot. None of these statements is related to any of the others, and each is proved using the definition of direct/inverse image and of intersection/union. When asked to prove such a statement as (c), the first thing you should do is write out the definition of the inverse images involved in the statement. The situation for (b) and (d) is the same. You cannot infer anything about one from the other.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I was fooled by the false symmetry.

Comment: "Each is proved . . ." You mean to say, each of the three *true* statements is proved from definitions. The false one is refuted with a counterexample.

Comment: Dear @bof, Yes, I shouldn't have said proved. Each statement can be addressed using the definitions.